# What is the probability that probability of a head in a coin toss is x?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Clearly we are not talking of an *unbiased* coin.
Hence, $p(H) = x$ itself is a random variable which can take a value between
 $ [0,1]$. Thus, my question is - what sort of distribution this $x$ can follow?

What it looks like, naively, that as $x \in \mathbb{R}$, point probabilities gets to 0. If I would have asked "what is the probability that $ a \le x \le b $ with 
$a,b \in [0,1]$ then, perhaps one standard way of answering would be $b-a$.

Taking this further, no matter what sort of distribution this $x$ follows, 
 I can see that when $a \to b$, the $p(H) \to 0$.

Hence, my question is, would be precise enough to state this point probability as 0 ?

Comment: if $x\in\mathbb R$, (excuse my french) $x/\mathbb R\to0$.

Comment: The uniform distribution is a highly implausible model.  One could get information towards a model by taking a few tens of thousands of coins and tossing each of them a few tens of thousands of times.